# FireBase Phone Authentication is giving invalid mobile number format error on KItKat but works fine on Nougat

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using `Firebase` Phone Authentication in my Android app. It works fine on Nougat but on KitKat it shows that mobile number is not of valid format. I have seen GitHub issues with Jio Indian numbers but non-Jio Indian numbers also gives same problem in KitKat.
Also in KitKat the number which is giving not valid mobile number error, works fine in Nougat.